# how can I create variables of function in every different function there's different argument in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'll directly give an example

if I wrote this

```
function say(word){
  console.log('word');
}
var func1 = say('hello');
console.log(func1());
```

I want to recieve: hello

Comment: `'word'` is a string, `word` is the argument -> `console.log(word)`

Comment: is this answer or correction @JuanMendes

Answer (score 1):

You need to return a function to call it,

```js
const say = (word) => () => word
const func1 = say('Hello')
console.log(func1())
```

Comment: good one, add timer by `console.time('timer')` before the code, and after the code add `console.timeEnd('timer')`